# "Failed to parse CONTROLLER for FaceMesh in Aura component"

Tags: lightning-aura-components, controller, aura-attribute

I am trying to use the FaceMesh object from the MediaPipe library to detect and track faces in a video stream in my Aura component. However, I am getting an error when I try to save my component that says "Failed to parse CONTROLLER for js://c.FaceMesh: org.auraframework.util.json.JsonStreamReader$JsonStreamParseException: Only functions are allowed in javascript controllers [2, 17]".

```
<!-- MyComponent.cmp -->
<aura:component>
    
    
  <ltng:require scripts="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/camera_utils/camera_utils.js,
                           https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/control_utils/control_utils.js,
                           https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/drawing_utils/drawing_utils.js,
                           https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/face_mesh/face_mesh.js"
                afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.scriptsLoaded}" />

  <div class="container">
    <video class="input_video"></video>
    <canvas class="output_canvas" width="1280px" height="720px"></canvas>
  </div>
</aura:component>
```

And here is my controller code:

```
({
  videoElement: null,
  canvasElement: null,
  canvasCtx: null,
  faceMesh: null,
  camera: null,

init: function(component, event, helper) {
  this.videoElement = component.find('.input_video').getElement();
  this.canvasElement = component.find('.output_canvas').getElement();
  this.canvasCtx = this.canvasElement.getContext('2d');

  this.faceMesh = new FaceMesh({locateFile: (file) => {
    return `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/face_mesh/${file}`;
  }});
  this.faceMesh.setOptions({
    maxNumFaces: 1,
    refineLandmarks: true,
    minDetectionConfidence: 0.5,
    minTrackingConfidence: 0.5
  });
  this.faceMesh.onResults(onResults.bind(this));

  this.camera = new Camera(this.videoElement, {
    onFrame: async () => {
      await this.faceMesh.send({image: this.videoElement});
    },
    width: 1280,
    height: 720
  });
  this.camera.start();
},

onResults: function(results) {
  this.canvasCtx.save();
  this.canvasCtx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvasElement.width, this.canvasElement.height);
  this.canvasCtx.drawImage(
      results.image, 0, 0, this.canvasElement.width, this.canvasElement.height);
  if (results.multiFaceLandmarks) {
    for (const landmarks of results.multiFaceLandmarks) {
      drawConnectors(this.canvasCtx, landmarks, FACEMESH_TESSELATION,
                     {color: '#C0C0C070', lineWidth: 1});
      drawConnectors(this.canvasCtx, landmarks, FACEMESH_RIGHT_EYE, {color: '#FF3030'});
      drawConnectors(this.canvasCtx, landmarks, FACEMESH_RIGHT_EYEBROW, {color: '#FF3030'});
      drawConnectors(this.canvasCtx, landmarks, FACEMESH_RIGHT_IRIS, {color: '#FF3030'});
      drawConnectors(this.canvasCtx, landmarks, FACEMESH_LEFT_EYE, {color: '#30FF30'});
      drawConnectors(this.canvasCtx, landmarks, FACEMESH_LEFT_EYEBROW, {color: '#30FF30'});
      drawConnectors(this.canvasCtx, landmarks, FACEMESH_LEFT_IRIS, {color: '#30FF30'});
      drawConnectors(this.canvasCtx, landmarks, FACEMESH_FACE_OVAL, {color: '#E0E0E0'});
      drawConnectors(this.canvasCtx, landmarks, FACEMESH_LIPS, {color: '#E0E0E0'});
    }
  }
  this.canvasCtx.restore();
},


afterRender: function(component, event, helper) {
    this.superAfterRender();
    this.init(component, event, helper);
  }
})
```

Comment: The fundamental issue is trying to load directly from the CDN. `ltng:require` requires you to use static resources, as per the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/ltng:require/documentation).

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with this code,

1. Make sure you declare all the variables within the function as the error clearly states,

so this for example the below lines should go within the Function context,

```
videoElement: null,
  canvasElement: null,
  canvasCtx: null,
  faceMesh: null,
  camera: null,
```

---

```
init: function(component, event, helper) {
      videoElement: null,
      canvasElement: null,
      canvasCtx: null,
      faceMesh: null,
      camera: null,
 }
```

If you have to share variables between the Functions use the Helper function or use the [attribute](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_attributes.htm) `aura:attribute` to hold the state.

2. Make sure to use [static resources](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/ltng:require/documentation) for all the third party JavaScript. The third party JavaScript from an external resource is blocked for Security reasons.

Comment: Tried that, but I think this won't work!

Comment: What is the error message last time you tried?